# How to stop support for 3.5Inch iPhone

Tags: iphone

I want to focus 4inch resolution.

I think "Required Device capabilities" can't do it.

Is there any solution?

Comment: your app has to support the 3.5 inch phones too. What will you do if your app is run on a 3.5 inch device ? From the current app submission standards, I think that your app will be rejected.

Answer (score 3):

You can’t prohibit an app from running on 3.5" displays. You *can* prevent it from running on older architectures. Simply compile it for `armv7s` or `arm64`—*not* armv7—and the app will refuse to run on anything other than an iPhone 5 or 5s.

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I will build with armv7s for my new app.